# Php text spinner

Tags: php

i spent time writing a rss feed aggregator and have come to find out it completely has no impact on seo. infact it could be damaging my website. i cant get rid of it as its a commonly used resource. So was wondering is there any hardcore php text spinner(synonimizer) out there. that way i could server crawlers/spiders with spun text. is this ethical? or would it cause more damage? please i need feedback.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but …huh? Why is an RSS feed damaging your SEO, what would a "hardcore php text spinner" do and why would that benefit you?

Comment: well rss feeds are seen by google as duplicate content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with andrewk - aggregating content from other websites won't directly benefit your own with regard to how search engines rank you.

As the feeds are an important part of your website I'd suggest supplementing them with original content, either written by yourself or outsourced. Freelance writers are easy to come by for a good stack of original content, and will help contribute towards your PR.

Alternatively, block the spiders from accessing the pages/areas which include aggregated feeds, so that search engines only crawl your original content.

Answer (score 4):

If you believe your RSS feeds are seen as duplicate content, simply block robots from indexing them.

On your site, create (or edit) the file http://yoursite.com/robots.txt, and add something like:

```
User-Agent: *

Disallow: /your/rss/here
```

Comment: +1 Better approach to solving the problem than mangling the RSS feed.

Answer (score 1):

text spinners are pumping crap out to the web.
It will definitely affect your website. You will get marked for duplicated and 'humanly' unreadable content.

you should invest your time in finding ways to get fresh new content.

my 2 cents